# Mapping $| y \rangle$ to $(-1)^{x \cdot y}| y \rangle$

Tags: quantum-circuit, unitarity, oracles

I was checking some QC lecture notes by Ronald de Wolf and I came across this exercise that I can't solve.

Page 27 (pdf page 35), question 5, part b link: [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/qcnotes.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Erdewolf/qcnotes.pdf)

A slightly edited version:

Given some input input bitstring $x \in \{0,1\}^N$ and a unitary oracle
\begin{equation}
  O_{x}: |i\rangle =
    \begin{cases}
      (-1)^{x_i} |i\rangle & \text{if $1 \leq i \leq n$}\\
       |i\rangle & \text{if $i=0$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Give a quantum algorithm that uses $O$ and to map  $| y \rangle \mapsto (−1)^{x·y}  | y \rangle$  for every $y ∈ \{0, 1\}^N$"

Can someone please suggest a solution or give some hints ?

I am thinking of applying the oracle twice, $  O_y O_x  | y \rangle $ Or maybe use a had  $:  H O_x  | y \rangle $ but I am not sure if that works as intended  we do get the $(-1)^{x y}$ but we also get some extra factor $1/\sqrt{2^n}$in the phase. I am not so sure which route to go...

Thanks

Comment: What's a query to a bitstring? What information do you get from such a query?

Comment: Are you able to solve it for $T=1$?

Comment: @CraigGidney  The condition about T is not the problem... It's how to build the mapping that I can't do. for the sake of conciseness, I edited the question to make it clearer  without opening the long pdf.

Comment: @TristanNemoz, please see the edited version, I hope it is clearer now without having to go through the lecture note and the previous chapter...

Comment: @user206904 Okay I'll be more direct. Break the problem into cases and solve cases in order to understand the full solution. Solve the problem for $T=1$ before you try to solve it for arbitrary $T$. If that's still too hard, solve it for $T=1,n=1$. Then for $T=1,n=2$. Then $T=1,n=3$. Then $T=1,n=4$. And hopefully by then you see the pattern that lets you solve $T=1$. Then do $T=2$. Then do $T=3$. Then general $T$.